# Why does this SQL injection have an equals symbol?

Tags: sql-injection, sql-server, ctf

I was reading into the basics of SQL injection attacks on w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

In the second example, I was curious as to why the equal sign was used. I have quoted within the line below.

> " or ""="

Is there any particular reason why an equals sign was used, or is it a placeholder for any character or symbol? Included below is an extract from the tutorial.

```
uName = getRequestString("username");
uPass = getRequestString("userpassword");

sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name ="' + uName + '" AND Pass ="' + uPass + '"'
```

Here is an example where credentials are John Doe and myPass.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name ="John Doe" AND Pass ="myPass"
```

Using the **" or ""="** as a username and password results in the follow SQL statement being executed by the database.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name ="" or ""="" AND Pass ="" or ""=""
```

I cannot picture in my mind how that would work, causing the SELECT * to reveal everything in the USERS table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL operator "AND" has higher precedence than "OR". Let add parentheses, to make the logic more clear:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (Name ="") or (""="" AND Pass ="") or (""="")
```

Assuming there are no empty names, the 1st expression, `(Name ="")`, will hold `false` for all rows. Because of similar reason, `Pass =""` will hold `false` and thus the whole 2nd expression `(""="" AND Pass ="")` will hold `false` for all rows. But the 3rd expression, `(""="")`, will hold `true` for **all** rows.

Thus, the `WHERE` clause will be equivalent to `true`:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (false) or (false) or (true)
```

Means:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (true)
```

In SQL there are no constants `false` and `true`. I use them only to make the effect easier to understand.

Since the `WHERE` clause computes to `true` for **all** rows, this SQL will return **all** rows from the table. If the login function tests if the result is not empty, such check will succeed, and the login will be accepted.

Comment: Question 1.   But the 3rd expression, (""=""), will hold true for all rows.  <--- Why would it hold true for ""="" because what I input into the username and password field was different? I put " or ""=" which looks different.

Comment: Question 2. How comes you did not write Something=""="" like you did with Name="" and Pass="" because I tried this with an SQL DBMS on some sample data and kept on getting no results? I am sure it is some syntax rule I am unaware of. Perhaps it is purposely wrong to cause a False evaluation? Sorry for my questions, your answer was amazing!

Comment: UPDATE sorry it means does empty string equal empty string "" = "" I see, just like 1 = 1 to make it evaluate to True!

Comment: @questioner: I don't understand you question 2. Why do you expect I should have written word *"Something"*? There is particular SQL. It contains particular field names *"Name"* and *"Pass"*. I am just explaining how this particular SQL works. And I don't understand what your mean by *"it is some syntax rule I am unaware of"*.

Comment: Sorry, what I did not realise earlier was ""="" was comparing two empty strings which evaluates to true, I stupidly thought it was checking whether the username or password field contained that string.